# MapBox React Native : 'Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

I try to install : [MapBox](https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl) but I have those errors :

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mapbox-react-native-mapbox- gl:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0.
Required by:
  project :mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl
> Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0.
Required by:
  project :mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6
> Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
    Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0

> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0.
 Required by:
  project :mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1
> Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
     Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
     Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
     Dependency path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.6' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
     Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
     Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
     Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
     Constraint path 'projekt:mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio' strictly '1.13.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
```

I tried the solutions found on the web, but nothing works.

This is my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1" } } 
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
 }
}
```

I tried lot of things : suppress node_modules and npm install, clean cache, restart all... I am sure it is a react-native version porblem, but I am quite new to gradle and I don't understant how to fix a specific version for com.squareup.

I don't even understand if I must fix the version 15 or 13 of com.squareup for the project. Downgrad the react native version doesn't please me, I tried and nothing changed. I had much more lines of error at install, and now, I am blocked at this step. That is very frustrating, because it stops my project at this point.

Have you an idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `app/build.gradle`, I had this issue once...

```
compile (project(':@mapbox_react-native-mapbox-gl')) {
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0') {
        force = true
    }
}
```

My root build.gradle (ignore the version numbers, obviously I haven't updated this project for a while) looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As the OP cannot create build, I have created one - this is how I did it. The issue is (that I was running into also) when you use npm install from the github repo Read Me, it for some reason doesn't install the correct SDK version from NPM. Therefore we have to rectify the `package.json` to force install from a GH url

(https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/1602)

Run:

`react-native init MyProject`

Go to: package.json and add in dependancies (at the top):

`"@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl.git"`

run

`npm install`

`react-native link`

`react-native run-android`

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but I tried a long time to apply this solution. I have this error : "Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip'.
Build file 'D:\Projects\VSCode\projekt\android\app\build.gradle' line: 155
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Project with path ':mapbox_react-native-mapbox-gl' could not be found in project ':app'.Java(0)" related to app/build.gradle. I try to fix it, but I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: Now I can compile the application, but, in the file I use mapbox, I have this error : "Module `react-native-mapbox-gl` does not exist in the Haste module map", but it appears in package.json in dependencies :  "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "git+https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl.git", ... I am going crazy with mapbox, I feel like I am near the soution but still nothing works...

Comment: Let me look at my implementation for you

Comment: well...I don't know why, but I am back to the original error message, with your solution @JRK...

Comment: Are you cleaning your builds?

Comment: now i have this error on directory rctmgl : "The project was not build since its build path is incomplete.Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project"

Comment: Do you have a github project I can look at?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I unistalled mapbox and now my project does not work at all, I have 'Unkown error' on the emulator, and nothing in debug tools or console. I am disappointed. I tried to start a new project before that and I only installed MapBox and follow all the instructions for Android and...it doesn't compile too.I have tons of error on dependencies version....i am broken

Comment: the only thing I see for this error is : Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.ng I see for error ...but I don't know where to put --warning-mode all :

Comment: I'll create a new build tomorrow and get you a GitHub repo, see if you can build that.

Comment: thank you, I'll start a new project, so it will be a clean environment to import my components one by one to see where is the problem. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @LuxAeterna - updated my answer mate, I've compiled it from a completely new project. (If you could check and accept the answer)

Comment: really thank you for your help, at a certain point, when you pass so long time to resolve a problem like that, you become crazy and things like your solution are far from my mind. Whereas it is simple, my brain breaked down from a long time. Thank you so much, have a nice day !

Comment: My final comment : I confirm all works fine, you saved my life @JRK ! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: No problem, its what SO is here for :)